# Unable to convert the CLOB data into String

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am trying to convert **`java.sql.Clob`** data into `String` by using **`SubString`** method (This method giving good performance compared with other). The clob data having near or morethan to **`32MB`**. AS my observation substring method able to to return upto **`33554342`** bytes only.

if clob data is crossing 33554342 bytes then this it's throwing below sql exception
**`ORA-24817: Unable to allocate the given chunk for current lob operation`**

EDIT 
CODE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    Main main = new Main();
    Connection con = main.getConnection();
    if (con == null)    {
        return;
    }

    PreparedStatement   pstmt   =   null;
    ResultSet   rs  =   null;
    String sql  =   "SELECT Table_ID,CLOB_FILE FROM TableName WHERE SOMECONDITION ";

    String table_Id = null;
    String directClobInStr  =   null;
    CLOB clobObj = null;
    String clobStr = null;
    Object obj= null;
    try {
        pstmt   =   con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs      =   pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())   {
            table_Id    =  rs.getString( "Table_ID" ) ; 
            directClobInStr =  rs.getString( "clob_FILE" ) ;
                      obj       =  rs.getObject( "CLOB_FILE");

            clobObj = (CLOB) obj;
             System.out.println("Table id " + table_Id);
             System.out.println("directClobInStr "   + directClobInStr);
             clobStr = clobObj.getSubString(1L, (int)clobObj.length() );//33554342
             System.out.println("clobDataStr = " + clobStr);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    finally {
        try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:- here `obj =  rs.getObject( "CLOB_FILE");` working but I am not expecting this. because I am getting `ResultSet` object from somewhere as Object. I have to convert and get the data from CLOB

Any Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Please show your code!

Comment: increasing the shared_pool_size and the java_pool_size might help

Comment: @Rajat, I have tried with by increasing java pool size. but no luck

Comment: @OldProgrammer:-  I have updated with code snippet.

Comment: What is the specific database version you are running?

Comment: @mmmmmpie,  `11.2.0.3.0 - 64-bit`

Comment: I think @OldProgrammer hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Where Can I get  the `source jar` and `javadoc` for **`OJDBC5.jar`** . Please share the url. (I didn't find in google)

Comment: Maybe OT: I'm not sure about JDBC, but at least in OCI you can ask Oracle database about recommended fetch chink size. And then you should fetch LOB by (multiply of) fech size. As @acesargl answered. AFAIK you are reaching limit of PGA, your session is unable allocate such a big buffer on DB server side.

Answer (score 1):

Instead:

```
clobStr = clobObj.getSubString(1L, (int)clobObj.length() );
```

Try something like:

```
int toread = (int) clobObj.length();
int read = 0;
final int block_size = 8*1024*1024;
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(toread);
while (toread > 0) {
    int current_block = Math.min(toread, block_size);
    str.append(clobObj.getSubString(read+1, current_block));
    read += current_block;
    toread -= current_block;
}
clobStr = str.toString();
```

It extracts substrings using a loop (8MB per iteration).

But remember that, as far as I known, Java Strings are limited to 2 GB (this is the reason why read is declared as int instead of long) and Oracle CLOBs are limited to 128 TB.